# replacing values based on different conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like below:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"location": ["a", "b", "c"], "store": [1,2,3], "barcode1" : [1, 0 ,25], "barcode2" : [4,0,11], "barcode3" : [5,5,0]})
```

[image: test]

I'd like to replace values of bar codes with "zero", when they are less than zero,"low", when they are less than a threshold (for example "5") and "ok" when they are above that threshold.however I do not want to write it in a loop, since my real dataframe is the size of (1415,402) and that would be much time consuming.

I have tried the below code:

```
test.replace(test.iloc[:,2:] <= 0 , "zero", inplace = True)
```

looks fine for replacing zeros. but when I want to go to next replacement like below:

```
test.replace(test.iloc[:,2:] <= 5 , "low", inplace = True)
```

I get this error "'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" and I think thats because the 0 values are now replaced with "zero".
therefore I'd like to do the replacements once at a time and without for loop.
Any help would be appreciated and sorry for long explanation.

Comment: add your expected output dataframe

Comment: when you do the 2nd replace, you already have 'zero`as text. you cannot compare text with integer, that is why you are getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with `iloc`:

```
m1 = test.iloc[:,2:] <= 0
m2 = test.iloc[:,2:] <= 5 

test.iloc[:,2:] = np.select([m1, m2], ['zero','low'], default='ok')           
print (test)
  location  store barcode1 barcode2 barcode3
0        a      1      low      low      low
1        b      2     zero     zero      low
2        c      3       ok       ok     zero
```

EDIT:

```
def a(test):
    test.iloc[:, 2:] = np.select([test.iloc[:,2:] <= 0, 
                                  test.iloc[:,2:] <= 5 ], ['zero','low'], default='ok')
    return test

def c(test):
    arr1 = test.values[:,2:]
    new = np.full(arr1.shape, 'ok', dtype=object)
    new[arr1 <= 5] = 'low'
    new[arr1 <= 0] = 'zero'
    return test.iloc[:,:2].join(pd.DataFrame(new,columns=test.columns[2:],index=test.index))

print (a(test.copy()))
print (c(test.copy()))
```

---

```
In [91]: %timeit (a(test.copy()))
36.6 ms ± 1.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [92]: %timeit (c(test.copy()))
26.9 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: What if don't want to change other values?

Comment: @xiutiqianshi - Can you explain more?

Comment: u change the other value to 'ok'

Comment: @xiutiqianshi - yes, exactly. `np.select` return default if not matched `m1, m2` masks.

Comment: But if I dont want to change the values,how can I do.This is my question,can u answer me ?

Comment: Sorry, then change `default='ok'` to `default=test.iloc[:,2:])`

Comment: @jezrael Hi there. I know this post is quit old and your answer helped me back then, however I am in a situation which my dataframe is so huge and using this method on it takes like ages. is there a more faster way of doing exactly this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mo.S - answer was edited. If still sloww, the best is post new question and add tag `numpy` with `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `cut` function -

```
import numpy as np
test["barcode1"] = pd.cut(test["barcode1"], [-np.inf, 0, 5, np.inf], labels=["zero", "low", "ok"])

  location  store barcode1  barcode2  barcode3
0        a      1      low         4         5
1        b      2     zero         0         5
2        c      3       ok       11         0
```